# Domain controller selection process

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory

I have several networks which are isolated from one another apart from one of the networks hosting the primary domain controller.

I am adding a new network, although when creating a domain controller on this network the domain name is not resolving to the PDC, rather it is selecting one of the other domain controllers in an isolated network and hence fails the dcpromo process.

How can I tell the soon to be domain controller on the new network to only use the PDC as its source of communication on the domain?

Comment: You don't actually have a PDC right? That would mean that you have windows NT. also, what does "adding a new network" mean? Are you adding a child domain? Adding DCs to an existing domain but in a new site? K

Answer (score 2):

You fix your existing topology and replication so you don't have any isolated networks that can't communicate back to your PDC emulator, and then it just works.  Don't go adding a new Domain Controller to an existing domain with issues like you describe, because all it does is set yourself up for a world of hurt.

Having said that, the `set` command can be used to change environmental variables, like `%logonserver%`, and if you want to defer fixing your AD topology until it's a catastrophic and painful disaster and promote this DC into a broken topology, that would be how you'd go about doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You control what computers authenticate where by configuring Active Directory Sites and Services properly. After you do that, the member server will authenticate against whatever DC(s) you tell it do, via subnet objects or site links.

Once it's a DC though, it won't need to authenticate against a different DC.